# Como descriptografar registros de uma coluna SQL - Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, sql-server-2012

Bom dia!

Galera, como descriptografar registros de uma coluna em uma consulta SQL.
O campo que quero descriptografar é a `coluna MAX(A.Descricao) [Descrição da Última Providência]`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,T.TarData,103) [Data de Abertura],
    CONVERT(DATE,T.TarVencimento,103) [Data de Vencimento],
    U.UsuNome [Responsável],
    UC.UsuNome [Cliente - Nome Fantasia],
    UC.UsuRazaoSocial [Cliente - Razão Social],
    T.TarID [N° da Tarefa],
    E.EstagioDesc [Estágio],
    S.StatusDesc [Status],
    C.Descricao [Cliente - ABC],
    TI.TipDescricao [Caminho],
    UC.UsuCGC [Cliente - CNPJ],
    CONVERT(DATE,T.TarFechamento,103) [Data de Fechamento],
    UG.UsuNome [Gerador],
    M.DsModulo [Módulo],
    p.ProNome [Produto],
    T.TarTitulo [Título],
    T.TarNumAtiv [Número de Providências],
    MAX(CONVERT(DATE,a.AtivData,103)) [Data da Última Providência],
    MAX(A.Descricao) [Descrição da Última Providência]
FROM Tarefa t
LEFT JOIN Usuario U ON u.UsuID = t.UsuIDResponsavel
LEFT JOIN Usuario UC ON UC.UsuID = t.UsuIDCliente
LEFT JOIN Estagio E ON e.EstagioID = t.TarEstagioID
LEFT JOIN Status S ON s.CodStatus = t.TarStatus
LEFT JOIN CurvaABC C ON C.CurvaID = UC.CurvaID
LEFT JOIN Tipo TI ON ti.TipID = t.TarTipID
LEFT JOIN Usuario UG ON ug.UsuID = t.UsuIDInclusao
LEFT JOIN Modulo M ON m.ModID = t.ModID
LEFT JOIN Produto P ON p.ProID = t.ProID
LEFT JOIN Atividade A ON a.TarID= t.TarID
WHERE T.ProjID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY T.TarID,T.TarTitulo, U.UsuNome, UC.UsuNome, UC.UsuRazaoSocial, UC.UsuCGC, 
    C.Descricao, E.EstagioDesc, S.StatusDesc, TI.TipDescricao, T.TarFechamento,
    UG.UsuNome, M.DsModulo, p.ProNome, t.TarNumAtiv, T.TarData, T.TarVencimento 
ORDER BY T.TarID
```

Comment: O que seria "descriptografar"? O conteúdo da coluna Descricao (tabela Atividade) está codificado?  //  Observe que a junção da tabela Atividade é do tipo left outer. Pode vir NULL.

Comment: Se a intenção é descriptografar , cadê os dados criptografados?

Comment: ele está vindo assim:0x456E766961646120656D3A2032372F30332F323031372031323A32343A33393C62723E4465.

Comment: Este campo não é do tipo `VARBINARY`? Se sim basta fazer `SELECT CAST(Descricao AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as Descricao`

Comment: isso abfurlan, deu certo. Valeu

Comment: Ok, vou postar como resposta!

Answer (score 2):

Não trata-se de Criptografia, seu campo aparentemente é do tipo `VARBINARY`, se sim basta fazer um [CAST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) para `VARCHAR`, exemplo:

```
SELECT CAST(Descricao AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as Descricao
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0770c/1)**